# Align headers' baselines

Tags: css, html

I have some markup as follows

```
  <header>
    <h1>{{site.title}}</h1><h2>&nbsp;{{site.subtitle}}</h2>
    <nav>
      <a href="/">Home</a> |
      <a href="/me.html">About Me</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

I want to align all the baselines, whilst floating the `<nav>` element to the right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following solution (in less):

```
header {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 900px;

  span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
  }   

  h1, h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
  }   

  nav {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    float: none;
  }   
}
```

I had to add a span around the header elements.